# alias for login page as /accounts

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess, .htaccess, folder

We have a magento website on /store folder.
Idea is, on root folder, index.php will have company website.

/store folder will have magento folder.

Idea is, `www.example.com/account` should load login form from

```
www.example.com/store/customer/account/login/
```

and

```
www.example.com/account/register
```

should load register form from

```
www.example.com/store/customer/account/create/
```

Can we do this using .htaccess?

I was trying following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/account
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /store/customer/account/login/ [NC,L]
```

this code redirects to /accounts to /store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/account        
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /store/customer/account/login/ [P]
```

It use P [Proxy flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) (which implies L flag too).
To use it, make sure you have mod_proxy_http and mod_proxy enable.

```
a2enmod proxy_http    
a2enmod proxy
service apache2 restart
```

These last commands can depend of your OS.

However, you need to know that Apache advice that you should not activate mod_proxy if your server is not secure ([see here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html)).

Comment: Will it work on xampp ?

Comment: One more thing... Magento could already have a redirection for non-existing page in the .htaccess.  Be sure to put your Rewrite command in the right place, before Magento instructions.

Comment: The Rewrite commands will works with XAMPP, but you will have to enable or install modules in the proper way. I don't know how works this part of XAMPP. I don't use it.

Comment: A bit of [documentation](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/wiki/How-to-enable-Apache-modules) for enable module on XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

in your root folder put the following in your `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^account /store/customer/account/login/ [R=301,NC,L]
    ...
</IfModule>
```

if users try to surf to `www.example.com/account` they will be redirected to `www.example.com/store/customer/account/create`. Keep in mind that the URL that the users see will then also changes to `www.example.com/store/customer/account/create` instead of `www.example.com/account`

Comment: Actually i need alias. It means that, customer should not see that they are on www.example.com/store/customer/account/create

Comment: sorry, didnt realise that that's your concern

Answer (score 0):

What you are expecting can be done using magento's url rewrite. 
Login to your admin panel and follow below steps

> 1) goto catalog->URL rewrite management
>
> 2)  -> click add URL Rewrite button
>
> 3) In create Url rewrite drop down select custom
>
> 4) Select store for your rewrite
>
> 5) In Target path field enter your URL which has to be shown to user i.e. account
>   6) In Request path field enter your URL which has to be redirected i.e. store/customer/account/login
>
> 7) In Redirect chose temporary or permanent as per your requirement 
>    Click Save

Now access your URL and it should work.